# Yup one of fields filled

Tags: reactjs, yup

my question is how can i validate with Yup if one of the fields is existing?

```
    const Schema = yup.object({
      firstname: yup.string().ensure().trim().required("There must be a name"),
      lastname: yup.string().ensure().trim().required("There must be a
      lastname")
       }
      );
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this should suffice your use case. You can always write additional tests by chaining them if you want!

```
const Schema = yup.object({
  firstname: yup.string().ensure().trim().required("There must be a name"),
  lastname: yup.string().ensure().trim().required("There must be a
  lastname")
})
.test('at-least-one-property', "you must provide at least one", value =>
  !!(value.firstname || value.lastname)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const notEmptySchema = yup.object({
  field: yup.string(),
  //...
}).test(
    'at-least-one-field', 
    'you must provide at least one field', 
    input => hasAtLeastOneField(input));

function hasAtLeastOneField(input) {
  let hasAtLeastOneInput = false;
  for (const [, value] of Object.entries(input)) {
    if (!!value) {
      hasAtLeastOneInput = true;
    }
  }
  return hasAtLeastOneInput;
}
```